# How to export function in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use the user function from that.

```
class GlobalParams {
    constructor() {
      this.user = '';
    }
    
    user = (user) => {
      if(!user) return this.user;
      this.user = user;
    }
  }
export default gp = new GlobalParams();
```

And use it in state as - user: gp.user(), but it says that 'user' is not exported.

Request:

```
getUserData() {
                fetch(`${API}/auth/user`, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    withCredentials: true,
                    credentials: 'include'
                })
                .then (response => response.json())
                .then (response => {
                    gp.setUser(response)
                })
                .catch (error => {
                    console.error (error);
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have duplicate property names in this class.

In the constructor, you define `this.user` as an empty string.
Then, on the line `user = (user) => {` you basically assign a function to `this.user`.

But, the constructor is called only when you do `new GlobalParams()`, so in the end `this.user` will be an empty string, not a function.

The solution: just change the name of the method:

```js
class GlobalParams {
  constructor() {
    this.user = "";
  }

  setUser = (user) => {
    if (!user) return this.user;
    this.user = user;
  };
}

export default new GlobalParams();
```

Now you would use it like this:

```js
import gp from "./GlobalParams";

gp.user // to get the user

gp.setUser("new user"); // to set the user
```

Comment: qp.user returns empty string, can you check my request in the question